# Return Timeframe of Concurrent Call Results

Tags: sql

Through the great help of this site, I've come up with the following SQL query to return highest concurrent calls in our phone system within an entered timeframe.   I'm accessing SQL Server 2012 via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.  What I'm now looking for, is to also return the timeframe (beginning and ending) that this peak concurrency had happened.

Here is the query:

```
With C1 AS (
  SELECT initiateddatetimeutc AS ts, +1 AS TYPE,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY initiateddatetimeutc) AS start_ordinal
   FROM interactionsummary
   WHERE initiateddatetimeutc >= '11/24/2017 11:00:00' 
     and initiateddatetimeutc <= '11/24/2017 17:00:00'
   UNION ALL
   SELECT terminateddatetimeutc, -1, NULL
   FROM interactionsummary
   WHERE initiateddatetimeutc >= '11/24/2017 11:00:00' 
     and initiateddatetimeutc <= '11/24/2017 17:00:00'
), C2 AS (
   SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ts, TYPE) AS start_or_end_ordinal
   FROM C1
)
SELECT MAX(2 * start_ordinal - start_or_end_ordinal) AS MaxConcurrent
FROM C2
WHERE TYPE = 1
```

Comment: Make it easy to help you, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and follow the instructions.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Sorry  a_horse_with_no_name, I'm accessing SQL Server 2012 via Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: jarlh, I'm not sure why that link is relevant, but I did read through that and feel I've met those points have been followed as best that I know how.  I apologize if I should have posted this differently.